# Tomcat can't start normally

Tags: tomcat8

Can someone help me solve the problem?
When I try to start tomcat by startup.bat or tomcat8.exe , tomcat can't start.But it can work in Eclipse. Error log is as below:

```
 25-Jun-2016 22:21:17.573 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
     org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8005]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:625)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Catalina]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:769)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 7 more
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:441)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 9 more
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:924)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 11 more
    25-Jun-2016 22:21:17.599 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
    25-Jun-2016 22:21:17.602 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
    25-Jun-2016 22:21:17.624 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stopInternal Stopping service Catalina
    25-Jun-2016 22:21:17.627 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
    25-Jun-2016 22:21:17.628 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
```

Comment: What OS? Which tomcat? What kind of configuration?  What version of java?  What you tried to solve it?  You cannot expect someone on the other side of a cable to know everything about your system.  Also, you should probably take this to [serverfault.com](http://serverfault.com/) instead.

Comment: Thank you.I found the problem at last.The problem is that when I deploy the springMVC project,the pom.xml is wrong so that tomcat8's server.xml is modified wrongly.